# App crashes when trying to initiate fragment on bottomSheet

Tags: javascript, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, bottom-sheet

The problem may be coming from my architecture but I'm not too sure.

Here's the problem.

I have an activity which initiate a fragment. The `.xml` file of that activity contains, a `FrameLayout` for the fragment (let's call it FragmentA) and a `CoordinatorLayout` which acts as a bottomSheet.

Inside the bottomSheet, there's another `FrameLayout` for an another fragment (let's call it FragmentB).

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the bottomSheet is expanded all the way, then, on its `FrameLayout`, I initiate FragmentB.

To save space, I decided to handle everything related to the bottomSheet in a different, separate class, named `BottomSheetManagement`

I, then, attached `BottomSheetCallback` on my bottomSheet and when its state is `expanded`, I call the method `initiateFragment(currentFragmentID, WorkFragment.newInstance())`.

This method is created in an interface called `FragmentHost` which is implemented in my mainActivity. Thus, when I call `initiateFragment(currentFragmentID, WorkFragment.newInstance())`, I'm actually calling the method of the same name in my mainActivity.

However, when I test my app and drag my bottomSheet to the top, i get the error message : `IllegalStateException : Activity has been destroyed.`

I don't understand how since in `initiateFragment(currentFragmentID, WorkFragment.newInstance())`, I make sure that the activity is still there (through `!isfinishing() && !isDestroyed()`)

What can I do?

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentHost {

    //BottomSheet Variables
    View bottomSheet;
    RelativeLayout bottomSheetHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow();
        }
        //Handle BottomSheet
        bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheetHeader = findViewById(R.id.BottomSheet_Layout_Header);
        bottomSheetManagement();
    }
    private void bottomSheetManagement(){
        BottomSheetManagement bottomSheetManagement = new BottomSheetManagement();
        bottomSheetManagement.handleBottomSheet(R.id.work_container, bottomSheet, bottomSheetHeader);
    }

    @Override
    public void initiateFragment(int containerID, Fragment fragment) {
        if (!isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(containerID, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

`BottomSheetManagement.java`

```
public class BottomSheetManagement {
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private int activeBottomSheetState;

    public void handleBottomSheet(int currentFragmentID, View bottomSheet, RelativeLayout bottomSheetHeader){
        FragmentHost fragmentHost = new MainActivity();
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetHeader.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            switch (bottomSheetBehavior.getState()){
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    break;
            }
        });
        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState){
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        fragmentHost.initiateFragment(currentFragmentID, WorkFragment.newInstance());
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

`main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/BottomSheet_Layout_Header">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    style="?attr/titleTextAppearance"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/work_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share layout file

Comment: @NagoorBhasha Sure, I just edited the question. Check it out.

Comment: may i know the exception you are getting

Comment: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerlmpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerlmpl.java:1566) at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:317) at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:282) at com.example.app.MainActivity.initiateFragment(MainActivity.java:44) at com.example.app.views.BottomSheetManagement$1.onStateChanged(BottomSheetManagement.java:36) at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.setStateInternal(BottomSheetBehavior.java:996)``` etc...

Comment: Do you need the entire exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the context of MainActivity already created to fragmentHost instead of creating a new context which you are doing by writing 'new MainActivivty()' which destroys previous MainActivity from where you called BottomSheetManagement and creates a new one.
Modify your BottomSheetManagement code to,

```
public class BottomSheetManagement {
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private int activeBottomSheetState;
    private FragmentHost fragmentHost;

    public void handleBottomSheet(FragmentHost context, int currentFragmentID, View bottomSheet, RelativeLayout bottomSheetHeader){
        fragmentHost = (FragmentHost) context;
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetHeader.setOnClickListener(v -> {
```

and in MainActivity code, change method to

```
private void bottomSheetManagement(){
        BottomSheetManagement bottomSheetManagement = new BottomSheetManagement();
        bottomSheetManagement.handleBottomSheet(this, R.id.work_container, bottomSheet, bottomSheetHeader);
    }
```